# ASP.NET Core 3.0 executing logic on application startup

Tags: asp.net-core

I have database records that for each of them I should have recurring jobs on application startup. I thought I could do that using `IHostedService` and DI'ing a scoped service but it's not possible because my scoped service has lesser lifetime. `IHostedService` requires a singleton service which leads to a dead end because ApplicationDbContext requires a scoped service.

> InvalidOperationException: Cannot consume scoped service 'Binance.Services.IBotService' from singleton 'Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService'.

I just need to execute that logic on application startup. What's best in such scenarios?

```
namespace Binance.Services
{
    public class BotHostedService : IHostedService
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;
        private readonly IBotService _botService;

        private int _numberOfBots;

        public BotHostedService(ILogger<BotHostedService> logger, IBotService botService)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _botService = botService;
        }

        public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Bot service is starting.");

            var bots = await _botService.GetAllAsync();
            _numberOfBots = bots.Count;

            for (int i = 0; i < _numberOfBots; i++)
            {
                Bot bot = bots[i];
                _logger.LogDebug($"{bot.Name} is starting. Symbol: {bot.CryptoPair.Description}, Interval: {bot.TimeInterval.Description}");
                RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate($"bot{i}", () => DoWork(bot), $"0/5 * * * *", TimeZoneInfo.Local);
            }
        }

        public void DoWork(Bot bot)
        {
            _logger.LogError($"{bot.Name} is working. Current time: {DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime()}");
        }

        public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Bot service is stopping.");

            for (int i = 0; i < _numberOfBots; i++)
            {
                RecurringJob.RemoveIfExists($"bot{i}");
            }

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is described in the [Consuming a scoped service in a background task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#consuming-a-scoped-service-in-a-background-task) section of [Background tasks with hosted services in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#consuming-a-scoped-service-in-a-background-task). The answer is to create a scope inside the service when needed. To do that, `IServiceProvider` must be added to the service's dependencies, eg:

```
public class BotHostedService : IHostedService
{
    //...
    private readonly IServiceProvider  _services;

    public BotHostedService(IServiceProvider services, ILogger<BotHostedService> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _services=services;
    }

    public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Bot service is starting.");
        using (var scope = _services.CreateScope())
        {
            var botService = scope.ServiceProvider
                                  .GetRequiredService<IBotService>();
            var bots = await _botService.GetAllAsync();
            ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! Can I also use that way if my service is singleton?

Comment: @nop yes. It doesn't matter what the lifetime of the calling service is.

Comment: If it's singleton you don't need to create a scope manually because an hosted service is registered as a singleton. You can just inject it through the constructor

Comment: @mcont if that were the case, there would be *no* need to create a scope.  A background service behaves like a singleton. Besides, keeping an expensive class like `DbContext` alive for the duration of an application's lifetime would cause serious concurrency problems

Answer (score 1):

You can inject a `IServiceProvider` through the constructor, and then create a scope when necessary, like this:

```cs
using (var scope = this.serviceProvider.CreateScope())
{
    IBotService botService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IBotService>();
    // use it
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I accepted the other answer because he was faster.

Comment: Actually it's the opposite but no problem :)